# I'm interested in the solution set satisfying the equation $\log_{10} p\times\log_{10} q=\log_{10} r$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, natural-numbers

The equation interested in is $\log_{10} p\times\log_{10} q=\log_{10} r$ where $p,q,r\in\mathbb N$ are natural numbers.

Here, I want not to consider some trivial solutions that make any one of logarithm terms integer, such as

$(p,q,r)=(10^2,10^3,10^6)$ or $(p,q,r)=(10,7,7)$

I guess there is no solution consist of natural numbers other than those trivial ones, but I'm having difficulty in verifying this..

So, could anyone give some answer to this problem?

Comment: HINT: $\log_{10}(p)+\log_{10}(q)=\log_{10}(r)\Leftrightarrow p+q=r$